# Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2(n+1)^{3/2}}{n^{3/2}+1}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to prove that the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2(n+1)^{3/2}}{n^{3/2}+1}$$ actually converges. However, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2(n+1)^{3/2}}{n^{3/2}+1}=2\neq0$$then the series cannot converge. But my book says it converges, so I don't know if that's a mistake or I'm missing something.

Comment: The book has a typo then.

Comment: You seem to be right, or you wrote something wrong.

Comment: I assume this is a calculus problem. If so, calculus texts often have a surprising number of errors in the answers, in spite of diligent attempts at proof-reading. I agree with the other comments. If you have copied the problem correctly, then you are correct that the series diverges.